# Проблема со строками в C

Tags: c, строки

Господа, доброго времени суток. Есть задача:

> Дана последовательность символов, состоящая из слов. Выделить в каждом
>   слове наиболее удаленную по алфавиту букву. Если от начала слова до
>   положения этой буквы все буквы упорядочены по возрастанию, то удалить
>   такое слово с сохранением структуры пробелов. Вывести на экран
>   отредактированный текст или сообщение «Нет», если удаления слов не
>   было. Определение упорядоченности по возрастанию соответствует
>   алфавитному порядку букв в слове.

Я написал два решения, оба не работают по неизвестной мне причине:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void)
{
    char str[100], word[100] = " ", word_arr[20][20]; 
    // str - вводимая строка, word - хранилище слова, word_arr - 2D массив слов
    int i, j = 0, k = -1, *last, t = 0;
    // i, j - счётчики букв, k - счётчик кол-ва слов
    // last - массив положений наиболее удаленной по алф. буквы в каждом слове
    // t - счётчик слов, подлежащих удалению
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
        if (str[i] == ' ' || i == strlen(str))
        {
            word[j] = '\0';
            k++;
            strcpy(word_arr[k], word);
            word[j = 0] = '\0';
        }
        else
            word[j++] = str[i];

    last = (int*)malloc((k + 1) * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; word_arr[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (word_arr[i][j - 1] < word_arr[i][j])
                last[i] = j;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= last[i] - 2; j++)
        {
            if (word_arr[i][j] < word_arr[i][j + 1])
                t++;
        }
        if (t == last[i] - 2)
            last[i] = -1;
    }

    t = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        if (last[i] == -1) t++;
    if (t = 0)
    {
        printf("No\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
        if (last[i] != -1)
        {
            for (j = 0; word_arr[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
                printf("%c", word_arr[i][j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

И второе:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void)
{
    char str[100], str2[100], word[100]; 
    //str - вводимая строка, str2 - строка после преобразований, word - временное хранилище слова
    int i, j=0, t, k=0, words=0, max=0;
    // i - счётчик для перехода по знакам строки, j - счётчик букв в слове 
    // t - счётчик для нахождения наиб. удаленной по алфавиту буквы, k - счётчик букв, удовл. условию
    // words - кол-во слов, подлежащих удалению, max - положение наиболее удаленной по алфавиту буквы
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || i == strlen(str))
        {
            word[j++] = ' ';
            for (t = 0; t < j; t++)
                if (word[t] < word[t + 1])
                    max = ++t;
            for (t = 0; t < max-1; t++)
            {
                if (word[t] > word[t + 1])
                    break;
                k++;
            }
            if (k != max - 1)
            {
                strcat(str2, word);
                words++;
            }
            j=0;
        }
        else
            word[j++] = str[i];
    }
    if (words == 0)
        printf("No");
    else printf(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

В первой программе съезжает последняя строка массива, вторая вовсе вылетает непонятно почему. Подскажите, что не так. Буду очень признателен!

Comment: Я плохо понял алгоритм программы, но... (пока скажу про вторую программу) очевидные ошибки: 1. Вы не инициализировали строки при объявлении. В итоге, в строке str2 куда Вы все прибавляете - изначально лежит какой-то мусор. я бы предложил им всем сделать так: `char str[100]={0}, str2[100]={0}, word[100]={0};`.

Comment: 2. Если я правильно понял, цикл по i (внешний) должен делить на слова, и эти слова сохраняются в `word`. Так вот, после каждого найденного слова (при переходе к новому) Вы это слово не очищаете. Снова получается мусор (который остается, если новое слово оказалось короче). Предлагаю на каждой итерации цикла после условного оператора делать как-то так: `memset(word,0,sizeof(word));`  3. Не столько ошибка, сколько... у меня есть некоторые сомнения в том, что имеет смысл цикл вести до `i <= strlen(str)` - ведь последний символ должен быть '\0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я закомментировал найденное неправильное место и добавил пару своих команд и еще printf() для отладки (можете удалить или использовать для дальнейшей борьбы).

У Вас неправильно был сделан поиск максимума (если я правильно понял это место).
Но это не сильно помогло работе, кажется все еще есть ошибки в алгоритме программы. Пока удаляет только одно слово за один раз (я тестировал на строке: "qwert jbjhbjb jhbjbjhb 12345 abcdefgh"). Первое попавшееся (в данном примере, удалило только 12345). А вот если подсунуть данные, чтобы не было удалений слов, то "No" не пишет :-( .
Или, возможно, я не совсем верно понимаю задание :-) .
В общем, программа с mingw-w64 gcc сейчас работает без "вылетаний" (кстати, с gcc она и не вылетала, просто в переменных мусор выводила) и есть что пилить дальше. Может, завтра на свежую голову (если коллектив не опередит) попробую остальные ошибки найти.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void)
{
char str[100]={0}, str2[100]={0}, word[100]={0}; 
//str - вводимая строка, str2 - строка после преобразований, word - временное хранилище слова
int i, j=0, t, k=0, words=0, max=0;
// i - счётчик для перехода по знакам строки, j - счётчик букв в слове 
// t - счётчик для нахождения наиб. удаленной по алфавиту буквы, k - счётчик букв, удовл. условию
// words - кол-во слов, подлежащих удалению, max - положение наиболее удаленной по алфавиту буквы
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
{
    if ((str[i] == ' ') || (i == (strlen(str))))
    {
        //++j;
        word[j++] = ' ';
        for (t = 0; t < j; t++)
            //if (word[t] < word[t + 1])
                //max = ++t;
             if (word[t] > word[max])   max = t;

        printf("VAK: max = %i\n",max); 

        for (t = 0; t < max-1; t++)
        {
            if (word[t] > word[t + 1])
                break;
            k++;
        }
        if (k != (max - 1) )
        {
            strcat(str2, word);
            words++;
        }
        j=0;
        k=0;
        memset(word,0,sizeof(word));
        max = 0;
    }
    else
        word[j++] = str[i];
    printf("vak: %s\n", word);
}
if (words == 0)
    printf("No");
else printf(str2);
return 0;
}
```

PS: да, естественно... еще на каждой итерации по i надо счетчик k очищать. если поставить k=0; - то все немножко лучше, но теперь есть ложное срабатывание на "qwert".

Comment: Я только немного изменил алгоритм и всё получилось! Большое спасибо, что показали, как создавать чистую строку и очищать память, в этом была основная проблема. Ну и про обнуление счетчиков я вчера забыл, поторопился.

Comment: Почему Вы использовали %i здесь printf("VAK: max = %i\n",max)?

Comment: @Watchman, да что первое под руку подвернулось :-) . Это аналог %d. Зачем его оставили - не знаю, видимо, чтобы сохранить совместимость со старыми версиями.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью рабочая версия программы.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "stdlib.h" 
#include "string.h" 

int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = { 0 }, str2[100] = { 0 }, word[100] = { 0 };
    int i, j = 0, t, k = 0, words = 0, max = 0;
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i]>'A' && str[i]<'Z') str[i] += 'z' - 'Z'; 
// Устраняется разница кодов заглавных и строчных символов
        if ((str[i] == ' ') || (i == (strlen(str))))
        {
            word[j++] = ' ';
            for (t = 0; t < j; t++)
                if (word[t] > word[max])
                    max = t;
            if (max < 2)
                k = -1;
// Если перед самой удаленной по алфавиту буквой в слове меньше двух символов, то удалять такое слово не нужно
            for (t = 0; t < max - 1; t++)
            {
                if (word[t] > word[t + 1])
                    break;
                k++;
            }
            if (k == (max - 1))
                words++;

            else strcat(str2, word);
// Если все буквы идут по алфавиту, счётчик собирает все k и добавляет единицу к числу удаленных слов. В противном случае записывает слово в новую строку для вывода
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
            max = 0;
        }
        else
            word[j++] = str[i];
    }
    if (words == 0)
        printf("No\n");
    else printf("%s\n", str2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```